# PHPunit no tests execute on Travis CI

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php, travis-ci

I'm been following a PHPUnit tutorial for the first time and my tests run fine locally. However, when running my tests on Travis CI, no tests are executed and my build exits with 0.

My directory structure and full code can be seen on the [repo](https://github.com/idavidmcdonald/phpunit-tutorial).

Build log from Travis CI [(Full build log)](https://travis-ci.org/idavidmcdonald/phpunit-tutorial/jobs/62845308)

```
1.51s$ curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
#!/usr/bin/env php
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...
Composer successfully installed to: /home/travis/build/idavidmcdonald/phpunit-tutorial/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
before_script.2
0.33s$ php composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
0.08s$ vendor/bin/phpunit --debug
PHPUnit 3.7.14 by Sebastian Bergmann.
Configuration read from /home/travis/build/idavidmcdonald/phpunit-tutorial/phpunit.xml
Time: 13 ms, Memory: 2.00Mb
No tests executed!
The command "vendor/bin/phpunit --debug" exited with 0.
Done. Your build exited with 0.
```

phpunit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true" bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>phpunittutorial/tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

.travis.yml:

```
language: php

php:
  - 5.4
  - 5.5

before_script:
  - curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
  - php composer.phar install

script: vendor/bin/phpunit --debug
```

My tests run successfully locally, however maybe there is an issue somewhere with my phpunit.xml file?

Comment: Some comment that may improve the situation: 1. Composer is already installed in Travis, there is no need to fully install it again. You might want to run `composer self-update` instead of running the curl install command. 2. Subsequently, Composer is called as `composer` directly, not as `php composer.phar`. 3. For debugging possible Composer issues, run the install command with verbose flags like `-vvv`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directory containing your tests is incorrect.

The correct path would be `phpUnitTutorial/tests`. Note that Windows does not care about case sensitivity, but everyone else in the world does. Best thing would be to always use lower case for paths, or double check you are using the correct case everywhere (PSR-0 and PSR-4 would require path names with the same case as the class name, which will usually include upper case letters).

And by the way: You should probably upgrade to a more recent version of PHPUnit. That old 3.7 series is not getting any more updates for years now, and the transition to 4.x isn't too steep - you should just do it.

Comment: The path was indeed the issue. I had conflicting versions on my local and github (my local directory was 'phpunittutorial' and github was 'phpUnitTutorial') after a change in case that had not been detected. I resolved my issue by changing the directory to 'app' and all required references. Also thanks for the bonus information about PHPUnit version and composer already being installed.

Comment: The same is true for MacOS: directories are case insensitive. I just resolved a similar issue with GitLab CI. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 0):

```
language: php

php:
 - 5.4
 - 5.5

install: composer install

script: ./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Not sure about `install: composer install`, probably can be omitted